# Unable to use ADO extension storage with VSS SDK with react js in jsx

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops-extensions

-Using ADO extension storage to persist data for our custom requirement

In Our environment with React js in jsx file tried to integrate with below approaches unable to debug
1.Collection approach for get /set
set:-

```
VSS.getService(VSS. ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then(function (dataService) {
// Set value in user scope
var myDoc = {
id: this." test",
__etag: -1,
value: “test2”
};

dataService.setDocument(“apis”, myDoc).then(function(doc) {
console.log("Doc id: " + doc.id);
});

});
```

Get-

```
VSS.getService(VSS. ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then(function(dataService) {
var collection = “apis”;
var docId= "test";
// Get document first
dataService.getDocument(collection, docId).then(function(doc) {
console.log(doc. Name);
});
});
```

2.Settings approach for get /set

Get:

```
VSS.getService(VSS. ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then(function (dataService) {
//Get value in user scope
dataService.getValue("test").then(function (value) {
console.log(value);

});
```

Set:

```
VSS.getService(VSS. ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then(function (dataService) {
// Set value in user scope
dataService.setValue(''test", “test2”,{scopeType: “Default”}).then(function (value) {

});
})
```

But unable to debug locally with both the approaches ,could you please suggest on this issue